# Docker container can't connect to another using a docker network

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

I use docker-compose to set up an API with some DBs and a seeder. Everything worked like a charm until a few days ago but now I can't seed the DB anymore.
Here's an example of my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    api:
      image: <API image>
      ports: {API_PORT}:5000 //Flask's default port
      depends_on:
        - db

    db:
      image: <DB image>
      ports: {DB_PORT}:27017 //MongoDB Default port

    db-seed:
      image: <seeder image>

// pretty classic docker-compose file, nothing fancy
```

The seeder uses the **docker network** to access the API container (*http://api:80/*) and seed  it. However, the seeder's script (written in Python) now returns an error when tying to connect to the API container:

```
$> docker-compose up db-seed
<LOT OF ERRORS>...
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f65e78a4310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

It seems like the seeder container can't access the DB container. What could be the cause of this error ? How could I fix it ?

Here's the **docker network inspect** of my network:

```
[{                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Name": "staging-sensei-api_default",                                                                                                                                                                                    "Id": "b5bd162d27f9a1addaacf1b0f2c09ad799d3ae195cc6e8c9cbb54bfffc27651c",                                                                                                                                                "Created": "2019-07-22T14:18:05.080114521Z",                                                                                                                                                                             "Scope": "local",                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Driver": "bridge",                                                                                                                                                                                                      "EnableIPv6": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                     "IPAM": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Driver": "default",                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Options": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Config": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Subnet": "172.26.0.0/16",                                                                                                                                                                                               "Gateway": "172.26.0.1"                                                                                                                                                                                              }                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Internal": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Attachable": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Ingress": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                        "ConfigFrom": {                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Network": ""                                                                                                                                                                                                        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "ConfigOnly": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Containers": {                                                                                                                                                                                                              "08672fe92d72b111f1a006a2ff20e885ef395a420525953b696672753cb73ff7": {
                "Name": "com.frcyber.sensei.elasticsearch",
                "EndpointID": "7ba9a1af1af5635d22c9cbd38fad8be222f351e5c0013f0280e2879cdd6e9e40",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "364f873d069e4ecd371cdd99ca952d1469ee875aacbf9ee2227bbf25ab65d841": {
                "Name": "com.frcyber.sensei.api",
                "EndpointID": "e5a3f4cd2099aff2a04efdeb7a5c5d0a8ade4248b76df048f20a8a75bf85ddba",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f4bfaf323a8c8c6300156d3091ec70f091fc3492175bfa00faa1717e4f83d2a2": {
                "Name": "com.frcyber.sensei.mongodb",
                "EndpointID": "b5df4e0d3721ffe5cd28ce55f642e6a0bc7f5be1a12cc49bb2eb12a58eb82e7a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "staging-sensei-api",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Also, I found out that it works when **API_PORT** is set to 5000:

```
api:
  ports: 5000:5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that it works in a specific case, i.e:

> Also, I found out that it works when API_PORT is set to 5000
>
> ```
> api:
>   ports: 5000:5000
> ```

I'd suggest the issue is not docker-side, but in how you setup your project. This suggestion is based on an assumption on my part: your db-seeder container uses the value in `API_PORT` as its port to connect to the api container (not clearly defined in your post, I'll assume it does for the following).

Since your python error shows `"api"` as the host, you're trying to connect to, DNS-wise this would be equivalent to IP 172.26.0.4, according to your `docker network inspect` output. On this IP, the container is listening on port 5000, regardless of `API_PORT`'s value (according to your docker-compose, since you always bind your host's `API_PORT` port to the container's 5000).

The weird thing is, you said it worked before, which should not have been the case, except if you had `API_PORT` as 5000.

If you want to connect inside the docker network on another port, you'll need to change something in the container, either at build or runtime, not only the host's port you bind to.

#### Addition: example of "configurability"

From your `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'

services:
    api:
      image: <API image>
      ports: "80:${API_PORT:-5000}" //Flask's default port
      depends_on:
        - db
      environment:
        - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT:-27017}
        - API_PORT=${API_PORT:-5000}

    db:
      image: mongo:latest
      command: --port ${DB_PORT:-27017}

    db-seed:
      image: <seeder image>
      environment:
        - API_PORT=${API_PORT:5000}
```

This doesn't expose your db port to the outside of your host. You'll need to retrieve both API_PORT and DB_PORT values from your shell's environement (or .env file) and use them as follows :

- connect to the api using `http(s)://api:$API_PORT`
- connect to the mongo using `db:$DB_PORT`
- launch the cgi server you use for your api in production (example for `uwsgi`) using API_PORT, for example at the end of your api container's `ENTRYPOINT` script:

```sh
# Some other config / checks / setup at runtime
exec uwsgi --port "$API_PORT" [ OTHER_OPTIONS ... ] path/to/your/application.py
```

Comment: Following your advice, I exposed the port 80 of my machine and linked it to the port 5000 of my container. In the seeder (inside the container), I changed api:80 to api:5000 and it works. Thanks

Comment: Good to know. Quick addition, from a security standpoint: considering you don't seem to need it, you shouldn't expose the DB_PORT on your host (if the api container is the only one you need to connect to the DB).
Check out the edition I made to my answer, with the options of default mongodb container (from Docker hub).